In jupyter notebok title of graph not showing.Why no title is there in the graph?
this is set of codes i ran
here is the graph,see everything is fine
this is the 2nd set of codes i ran, in the imaage u can see there is no title
i was trying to plot a count graph,i wrote the code for title that is plt.title('top 15 cities count')
No error is thrown but still no title is produced.
the problem is i just ran similar codes before this one and that worked fine

Welcome to StackOverflow.  Note that at StackOverflow, code is needed in text form, never as image.  Also, test data is needed, either as text or as code, in order to create a minimal reproducible example. You might want to check out the help center.

plt.title()

is a function, you are using it correctly in code #1, but in code #2 you are doing
plt.title=("title")

which should be
plt.title("title")


Note that plt.title=("title") is worse than wrong.  It also overwrites the real plt.title() function, making it inaccessible until you restart the environment.
